# New Firebase database data not returning

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure what the issue is but I have a well structured data table in Firebase's backend but when I try to retrieve it in Xcode/iOS, nothing returns.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
   FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"recaps"];
    [ref keepSynced:YES];

    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    [[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"author"]
     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
     withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshotLst) {
         self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

         for(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot in snapshotLst.children){

             NSDictionary* data = snapshot.value;
             [data setValue:[snapshot ref] forKey: @"firebaseRef"];
             [data setValue:[snapshot priority] forKey: @"priority"];
             [self.dataArray addObject:data];
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

         }
         [self.recapTable reloadData];
     }];
```

The UITableView is completely blank. Here's the twist, when I switch to another database created a few days ago, everything works fine.

Comment: try like this `for (NSDictionary *recent in [snapshotLst.value allValues]) { ... }`

Comment: BB Central[467:61139] -[NSNull allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance :(

Comment: ok try this ... .`[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"author"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.value != [NSNull null])
            {
                for (NSDictionary *recent in [snapshot.value allValues]) { ... } } }`

Comment: Thank you! It is still blank :( Could it be an issue with the backend? Why are some databases working while others aren't?

Comment: Ugh, the security rules were all messed up! Sorry for the bother!

Comment: It sure is! Only took me ... all day -.-' Thank you for your help!